# Subtraction Aggregate Mongo Document Golang

Tags: mongodb, go

i have this document in mongo

```
{
  "_id": {
    "$oid": "649d3d688a1f30bf82e77342"
  },
  "test_value": {
    "$numberLong": "10"
  }
}
```

i want to subtract "test_value" by one with this golang code

```
    jsonInput := []map[string]interface{}{
        {
            "$match": map[string]interface{}{
                "test_value": 10,
            },
        },
        {
            "$set": map[string]interface{}{
                "test_value": map[string]interface{}{
                    "$subtract": []interface{}{"test_value", 1}},
            },
        },
    })


    value, bsonByte, errMarshal := bson.MarshalValue(jsonInput)
    if errMarshal != nil {
        modules.DoLog("ERROR", "", "MongoService", "aggregateDocument", "cannot Marshal jsonInput to BSONByte", true, errMarshal)
        ctx.IndentedJSON(200, gin.H{
            "error": errMarshal.Error(),
        })
        return
    }
    fmt.Println(value)
    
    bsonD := bson.A{}

    errUnmarshal1 := bson.UnmarshalValue(value, bsonByte, &bsonD)
    if errUnmarshal1 != nil {
        modules.DoLog("ERROR", "", "MongoService", "aggregateDocument", "cannot Unmarshal BSONByte to BSOND", true, errUnmarshal1)
        ctx.IndentedJSON(200, gin.H{
            "error": errUnmarshal1.Error(),
        })
        return
    }
    
    _, err := Client.Database("rhanov_queries").Collection(collectionName).Aggregate(ContextMongo, bsonD)
    if err != nil {
        modules.DoLog("ERROR", "", "MongoService", "aggregateDocument", "cannot aggregate document to Mongo", true, err)
        ctx.IndentedJSON(200, gin.H{
            "error": err,
        })
    }
```

and i get this error

"cannot aggregate document to Mongo. cannot marshal type primitive.A to a BSON Document: WriteArray can only write a Array while positioned on a Element or Value but is positioned on a TopLevel"

what did i do wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```golang
"$subtract": []interface{}{"test_value", 1}
```

Please note that here `"test_value"` is a literal. The expression means subtract the number 1 from the string `test_value`, which is invalid and is not what you want. You want to refer to the field path instead. So you should prefix it with `$` (see [aggregation expressions](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/meta/aggregation-quick-reference/#std-label-aggregation-expressions)). Here is the corrected code:

```golang
"$subtract": []interface{}{"$test_value", 1}
```

---

**PS 1**:

To make it easy for others to look into the issue, please provide a minimal executable reproducer in the future, such as:

```golang
package main

import (
    "context"
    "fmt"

    "go.mongodb.org/mongo-driver/bson"
    "go.mongodb.org/mongo-driver/mongo"
    "go.mongodb.org/mongo-driver/mongo/options"
)

func main() {
    jsonInput := []map[string]interface{}{
        {
            "$match": map[string]interface{}{
                "test_value": 10,
            },
        },
        {
            "$set": map[string]interface{}{
                "test_value": map[string]interface{}{
                    "$subtract": []interface{}{"test_value", 1},
                    // `test_value` should be prefixed with $ like this:
                    // "$subtract": []interface{}{"$test_value", 1},
                },
            },
        },
    }

    typ, buf, err := bson.MarshalValue(jsonInput)
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    fmt.Println(typ)

    var bsonD bson.A

    if err := bson.UnmarshalValue(typ, buf, &bsonD); err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }

    client, err := mongo.Connect(context.Background(), options.Client().ApplyURI("mongodb://localhost"))
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    collection := client.Database("demo").Collection("values")
    cur, err := collection.Aggregate(context.Background(), bsonD)
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    defer cur.Close(context.Background())
    for cur.Next(context.Background()) {
        fmt.Printf("%+v", cur.Current)
    }
}
```

And initialize the collection data with:

```js
db.values.insert({ _id: ObjectId('649d3d688a1f30bf82e77342'), test_value: 10 })
```

(executed in [MongoDB Shell](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/mongodb-shell/))

With the package `go.mongodb.org/mongo-driver@v1.12.0` and `mongo:5.0.8`, the error I got is:

```
panic: (TypeMismatch) Failed to optimize pipeline :: caused by :: can't $subtract int from string
```

---

**PS 2:**

In case you don't know, you can create the `bsonD` variable like this directly:

```golang
bsonD := bson.A{
    bson.M{
        "$match": bson.M{
            "test_value": 10,
        },
    },
    bson.M{
        "$set": bson.M{
            "test_value": bson.M{
                "$subtract": bson.A{"$test_value", 1},
            },
        },
    },
}
```

---

**PS 3**:

The code you show has a syntax error (the end of the short declaration of `jsonInput` has an extra `)`). After correcting this error, I don't think it can cause the error you show in your question. I believe the error is for another `jsonInput` value.